# Can't resize through Gparted

Tags: gparted

I can't resize `/dev/sda2` in Gparted.

[image: Gparted]

Comment: Please give us the error you are getting.

Comment: @AndroidDev You can see that all partitions are mounted.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `gparted` cannot resize mounted partitions, and the partition you are trying to resize is Ubuntu's root partition. You will have to boot from a Live CD/USB and resize your partition from there. There are many guides for creating a live CD/USB around, such as [this one](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) (for creating a live USB from Ubuntu) and [this one](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) (for creating a live USB from Windows).

Comment: You might want to include directions for downloading and burning the ISO...

Comment: @AndroidDev There is no need in this answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 - It was just a suggestion. I didn't say he *needed to* :)